# Applying Low rank approximation to learnable parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, svd, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to understand whether it makes sense to apply Low-rank approximations to learnable parameters in a class. The goal is to reduce parameter counts.

I have the following custom module :

```py
class CustomPara(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, num_blocks, in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size):
        super(CustomPara, self).__init__()
        self.coefficient_shape = (num_blocks,1,1,1,1)
        blocks = [torch.Tensor(out_planes, in_planes, kernel_size, kernel_size) for _ in range(num_blocks)]
        for i in range(num_blocks): init.kaiming_normal_(blocks[i])
        self.blocks = nn.Parameter(torch.stack(blocks)) # this is what we will freeze later

    def forward(self, coefficients):
        final_blocks =  (self.blocks*coefficients).sum(0)
        return final_blocks
```

Is it possible to reduce the number of learnable parameters here using Low-rank adaptation on the `blocks` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the idea is introduced in the paper [LoRA: Low-Rank Adaptation of Large Language Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09685).

The key idea is that any matrix W of shape n * m and rank r can be written as multiplication of two matrices A, B such that A has shape n * r and B has shape r * m.

by introducing A, B as trainable matrices instead of W itself you can decrease  the number of trainable parameters with a little bit of decrease in model performance.